# Share variables between projects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution with some projects. One of this projects is the one I've defined as main, also his class has a main Method.

Inside this class, I've defined some properties public and static. What I want to to is access to this properties from other project file. For example:

**Project A:**

```
namespace Cobra
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static int A;
        public static int B;
...
```

**Project B:**

```
namespace Net
{
    public class HttpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        ...
        public void ProcessRequest()
        int a =Cobra.Program.A;
        int b =Cobra.Program.B;
...
```

How can I do this??

**EDIT:**

If I add **Project A** as reference in **Project B**: *"Adding this project as a reference, there will be a circular dependency."*

**Project B** contain some other files, so having a reference to **Project B** in **Project A** is needed.

Comment: Are the projects in the same solution? If so just include the project as a reference, If not,you could use reflection to load the dll

Comment: Yes it is, but "using Cobra" in B tell me that type or namespace can't be found.

Comment: Did you add the reference and is the referred project compiling without exceptions

Answer (score 6):

In Project B, Add a reference to Project A and add a `using Cobra` statement to Project B wherever you want to access something from the Cobra (Project A) namespace.

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tried it before asking here. "using Cobra" in B tell me that type or namespace can't be found.

Comment: That does work, if it doesn't then you haven't added the reference.

Comment: When I try to add: "Adding this project as a reference, there will be a circular dependency."

Comment: Then you already have a reference to project B in project A. You can't do that, as the error states.

Comment: Project B contain some other files, so having a reference to Project B in Project A is needed.

Comment: Well you can't have circular references, so you'd have to change your project layout.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference to Project A to project B - right click on the project node in the solution explorer, select references, then projects then Project A.

You will then have access to all the types in Project A.

See [this How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comments to other answers it sounds like your problem is really that you have a circular dependency which you need to break.  Generally the way to do that is to factor out an interface and place it in a third project that both other projects can reference so instead of

```
class Foo //foo lives in project 1 (depends on project 2)
{
    public Bar GetNewBar()
    {
        return new Bar(this);
    }
    public void DoSomething(){}
}

public class Bar //bar lives in project 2 (depends on project 1 -- cant do this)
{
    public Bar(Foo parent){}
}
```

you have

```
class Foo: IFoo //foo lives in project 1 (depends on project 2 and 3)
{
    public Bar GetNewBar()
    {
        return new Bar(this);
    }
    public void DoSomething(){}
}

public class Bar //bar lives in project 2 (depends on project 3)
{
    public Bar(IFoo parent){}
}

public interface IFoo //IFoo lives in project 3 (depends on nothing)
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Manu,

It is possible through reflection. The following is the solution to your problem.

You have created 2 projects

Project B -- having namespace "Net", class "HttpHandler"

Project A -- having namespace "cobra", static class "Program" and having reference of Project B

Now your problem is you need to access the class "Program" in Project B without giving reference of Project A to Project B because then the solution will not build as it will give cyclic reference error.

Check out the following

**Project A**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Net;

namespace Cobra
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static int A { get; set; }//Getter/Setter is important else "GetProperties" will not be able to detect it
        public static int B { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpHandler obj = new HttpHandler();
            obj.ProcessRequest(typeof(Program));
        }
    }
}
```

**Project B**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Net
{
    public class HttpHandler : IHttpHandler 
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(Type cobraType)
        {
            int a, b;
            foreach (var item in cobraType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
            {
                if (item.Name == "A")
                    a = (int)item.GetValue(null, null);//Since it is a static class pass null
                else if (item.Name == "B")
                    b = (int)item.GetValue(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is of some help.

Regards,

Samar

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a using directive at the top of project B's file:

```
using Cobra;
```

And add project A as a reference in project B.

Comment: When I try to add reference: "Adding this project as a reference, there will be a circular dependency."

Comment: As @CodeCaster said in his reply:  Then you already have a reference to project B in project A. You can't do that, as the error states.