# Static Data Member Not Being Shared In 2 Projects Under Same Solution C#

Tags: c#, wpf, static-members, access-modifiers

I have 2 projects in same c# solution. One project is normal wpf application and other one is windows service. When wpf application updates some variables in database, windows service needs to update accordingly. 
In my wpf application, I have a save method which updates a static field like

```
 private void ConfigurationPanelSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      bool isSuccess = SaveData();
      if (isSuccess)
      {
           DatabaseInteractivity.HasChanges = true; //static member to indicate data has been changed
      }  
  }
```

In windows service project, i have DatabaseInteractivity object and a timer event which is being called after 30 second interval (to see if data has been changed, if changed it re-reads some configurations)

```
 private void timer_elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (DatabaseInteractivity.HasChanges)
     {
         ConfigurationReader.ReadConfiguration();
         DatabaseInteractivity.HasChanges = false;
     }
 }
```

The problem is, when i save data through wpf application, it updates the static member (HasChanges) of DatabaseInteractivity class to true and when timer_elapsed event is called, HasChanges in windows service project is always false.
Shouldn't it be true for the first time when timer event is called?
I have read many articles and different approaches but I'm interested to know why it's not happening.

Comment: They are 2 separate executables. You can't use a static property like that. Static properties are only shared within the same process.

Comment: Not Even if i have referenced one project from the other?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209345/share-variables-between-projects

Comment: @pquest Strictly speaking, each `AppDomain` will have its own copy of static fields. So *Static properties are only shared within the same `AppDomain` not process*

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ah you are correct

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't how static members work. Your WPF application and your service will be running in two separate processes. As they exist in different application domains, each process has its own version of the static member `DatabaseInteractivity.HasChanges`. They are completely unrelated to each other; they exist in different locations in memory. Changing one will have no effect on the other.

You need to look into inter-process communication. For example, your Windows service could provide a [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) service end-point, to which your WPF application could connect. The end-point would have a method that the application would call to notify your service that data had been saved.

Answer (score -1):

Static objects are static accross the thread you're running on.
I'm guessing you are running a wpf application thread and a windows service thread.
Even if the dll's (aka sources) are the same, they are still running from a different thread and they can't access each others variables.