# How to share a variable between the assemblies

Tags: c#, static

I want to share a value between assemblies. The changes in the value in one assembly should reflect to other.

I have a base class which has a public static variable. This variable will be changed in every child class which is present in different assemblies. I want this value to be updated each time before changing.

Comment: Can you please provide some code? Its easier to help you when you have a specific question.

Comment: Why not merge assemblies if they're so dependent on each other?

Comment: Also have a llok at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209345/share-variables-between-projects

Comment: Why not write it to a file? This would be more reliable in terms of persistence (in the case of one assembly 'failing' somehow) and you would benefit from the metadata, storage options and security of a file on disk.

Comment: Are they in the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Decorator design pattern provides such features: Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp

You may visit too:
http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern